# SQL Server Find Max and Min in Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and have a table like this:

| DATE | ITEM | BUYER | QTY_BUY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM A | TOMMY | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM A | BENNY | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM A | ANDY | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM A | JOHN | 8 |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM B | TOMMY | 2 |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM B | BENNY | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM B | ANDY | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM B | JOHN | 6 |
| 2022-01-02 | ITEM A | TOMMY | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 | ITEM A | BENNY | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | ITEM A | ANDY | 5 |
| 2022-01-02 | ITEM A | JOHN | 6 |

I want to show top buyer and min buyer group by date and item, so it will look like:

| DATE | ITEM | TOP_BUYER | TOP_QTY | MIN_BUYER | QTY_MIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM A | JOHN | 8 | ANDY | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | ITEM B | BENNY | 10 | TOMMY | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | ITEM A | JOHN | 6 | BENNY | 0 |

Please help me to do that, I try so many trick but cannot reach it. Thanks in advance

Comment: "I try so many trick but cannot reach it." please show us what you tried

Answer (score 1):

We can handle this requirement using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE, ITEM ORDER BY QTY_BUY) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE, ITEM ORDER BY QTY_BUY DESC) rn2 
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT DATE, ITEM,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN BUYER END) AS TOP_BUYER,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN QTY_BUY END) AS TOP_QTY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN BUYER END) AS MIN_BUYER,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN QTY_BUY END) AS QTY_MIN
FROM cte
GROUP BY DATE, ITEM
ORDER BY DATE, ITEM;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use first_value + partition over

This query was tested inside SQL Server

```
select distinct [date], Item
    , FIRST_VALUE(buyer) OVER (partition by [date], item ORDER BY qty_buy desc) AS Top_Buyer
    , FIRST_VALUE(qty_buy) OVER (partition by [date], item ORDER BY qty_buy desc)  AS Top_Qty
    , FIRST_VALUE(buyer) OVER (partition by [date], item ORDER BY [date], item, qty_buy asc) AS Min_Buyer
    , FIRST_VALUE(qty_buy) OVER (partition by [date], item ORDER BY [date], item, qty_buy asc) AS Qty_Min
from testtable
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using simple group by and outer apply,
see this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FXKVya0W)

```
select t.bdate,
       t.item,
       max(tb.buyer) as top_buyer,
       max(t.qty) as top_qty,
       max(mb.buyer) as min_buyer,
       min(t.qty) as qty_min
  
from   test t
  outer apply ( select  top 1 t2.buyer
                from   test t2
                where  t2.bdate = t.bdate
                and    t2.item = t.item
                order by t2.qty desc
              ) tb
  outer apply ( select  top 1 t2.buyer
                from   test t2
                where  t2.bdate = t.bdate
                and    t2.item = t.item
                order by t2.qty
              ) mb
  
group by t.bdate,
       t.item
order by t.bdate
```